# setState randomly failed which is caused by component unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing a weird situation ...

The setState sometimes worked fine, but sometimes will get the warning for setting state to the unmounted component.

If the user's cart is undefined, then call the API to get the cart information and set the state.

```
  const loginData = () => {
    const isUnmounted = useRef(false);

    const handleData = () => {
      if (isUnmounted.current) return false;

      const setData = (user) => {
        //setCart failed sometimes, because of setting State to the unmount component
        if (cart == undefined) getUserData((response) => setCart(response.cart));  
      }

      if (userData !== null) {
        setUserData(user);
      }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      handleData();

      return () => {
        isUnmounted.current = true;
      }
    }, [])
  }
```

When I enter the page contain this component, it will sometimes success to work.
And the other time the page crashed because cart can't be set with the unmounted component (will get the warning in console), and the further `cart.id` will crash the process.

Looks like it just happened randomly...

Sometimes the process crash when I just enter the page,
but sometimes I can enter the page and refresh the page multiple times then the page crashed ...

Have no idea what is happened. May anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like there's a lot more code. I can't spot anything wrong in terms of state, but it does look like you're using useEffect inside of a function, which breaks the first Rule of Hooks, so that might be a good place to start: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: @JayKariesch 
Ah ... right, looks like I didn't follow the rule. Thanks for reminding me. And yes, there are lots of code and the structure is a little bit complicated for me to destruct to post in the question. I will try to solve the problem from using useEffect correctly first. Thanks again!